# Is the GT430/GT520 enough for 1080p flash?

Tags: nvidia, hardware, flash

**UPDATE 1:**

It seems that the gt520 is better at hd flash decoding that the gt430. Does anyone know if the gt520 is able to play 1080p video smoothly and if it can have 2 monitors connected to it at the same time for a larger desktop?

**ORIGINAL:**

Now that flash 10.3 is out for ubuntu which apparently has hardware acceleration, I just wanted to know if the gt430 graphics card would be enough to play 1080p flash files **directly from the browser** smoothly?

Comment: Just tested with Nvidia 8600GT (and its quite old nvidia card) and this youtube 1080p video -- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BvuvgV3w33o -- is played without problems (fullscreen 1280x1024).

Comment: Which CPU do you have?

Comment: How do you watch fluid 320p flash? My ordinary YouTube doesn't work full-screen in Ubuntu.

Comment: 240p, 320p, and 480p seem fairly smooth for me.  This was't the case a few months back.  320p and 480 improved greatly after installing flash 10.3 for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GT520 and GT430 should be sufficiently capable of playing 1080p Flash Video.  My 8800 GTS is capable, and is significantly less powerful then either of those cards.

The [official recommendation for system specs from Adobe for 1080p playback](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/systemreqs/) on Linux are;

```
1.8GHz Intel Core Duo, AMD Athlon 64 X2 4200+, or faster processor 
512MB of RAM
64MB of graphics memory
```

In addition [a list of NVidia GPUs](http://www.nvidia.com/object/gpus_supporting_adobeflash.html) which support hardware acceleration with Flash 10.3.  I should note that this requires the [proprietary NVidia driver](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia) with VDPAU.

Comment: Just wanted to confirm, do you mean you can play 1080p flash in a browser using your 8800GTS on Linux with flash 10.3?

Comment: Also, I have a Pentium 4 2.8GHz (hyperthreading) cpu.  Will this CPU with the GT520 be enough to handle 1080p flash smoothly on websites via a web browser?

Comment: I believe your problem is most likely CPU bound.  That CPU is a bit light.  It does meet Adobe's minimum requirements for Flash 10.3 (Intel Pentium 4 2.33GHz, AMD Athlon 64 2800+ or faster processor (or equivalent)), but it does not meet it for 1080p playback.  The 1.8 Ghz Intel Core Duo is significantly faster then the 2.8 Ghz Pentinum 4.  Yes, I can confirm my 8800 GTS with a 3.0 Ghz Intel Core 2 Duo can playback 1080p flash in a browser with 10.3 on Ubuntu 11.04.

Answer (score 0):

I have nvidia 9800GTX+ and 1080p videos work smooth without any problems. It should be noted that I use proprietary drivers.

Comment: Just wanted to confirm, do you mean you can play 1080p flash in a browser using your 9800GTX+ on Linux with flash 10.3?

Comment: Also, I have a Pentium 4 2.8GHz (hyperthreading) cpu.  Will this CPU with the GT520 be enough to handle 1080p flash smoothly on websites via a web browser?

Comment: @oshirowanen affirmative, I can play flash movies in such resolution. But I have more powerful CPU then you: AMD X2 3100Mhz.